# Eclipse/STS auto-correcting "new" as "newEmail"

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, springsource

I am using Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.5.0.RELEASE Build Id: 201404011851, which is based on Eclipse.

The auto-correct works great, but it is annoying on some cases. The worst case is when I type "new" followed by a space and STS replaces with "newEmail".

I do know how to turn the auto-correction off, but what I really want is to just remove the new->newEmail entry from the list.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling STS ?

Comment: This is not the kind of behaviour that is affected by restart. I have, however, restarted STS many times since, and the behaviour didn't change.

Comment: reinstalling != restart

Comment: why would I need to reinstall? STS is working as expected, I just want to change the way it works.

Comment: Since editing the Eclipse/STS dictionary is undocumented, and you are having an undesired behavior, one could argue that reinstalling would do reset to the default one which doesn't have this. Or you could check in **Prefereces -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Spelling** and remove a user dictionary that might be faulty.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but reinstalling and removing the dictionary didn't work. The dictionary was actually empty.

Comment: What you're describing is not any feature of Eclipse that I know of. Content-assist is triggered manually (the default is Ctrl+Space or `.` for Java code), not every time you press Space. Does it auto-insert other things when you press Space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a Java code template that's being inserted. In Preferences, look in **Java** > **Editor** > **Templates** to see if there is something that looks like the culprit. You can edit those templates and remove the option to auto insert.

Also under **Java** > **Editor** > **Content Assist** > **Advanced** you can disable entire groups of proposals, if this is one that is coming from a group that you can identify.

Comment: Content Assist didn't do it, and the options "Bindings" it was just for keyboard shortcuts. Sorry.